# What kind of JOIN statement do I need?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I have two tables PROCESS and STEP and some data inside as show below. (They have 1-N relationship.)

```
PROCESS ->

ID START_TIME STARTED_BY STATUS
1  31/08/2012 User1      FINISHED
2  31/08/2012 User2      FINISHED
3  05/09/2012 User3      ACTIVE

STEP ->

ID PROCESS_ID START_TIME END_TIME   STATUS
1  1          31/08/2012 02/09/2012 FINISHED  
2  1          02/09/2012 03/09/2012 FINISHED    
3  1          03/09/2012 10/09/2012 FINISHED  
4  2          31/08/2012 04/09/2012 FINISHED  
5  2          04/09/2012 06/09/2012 FINISHED  
6  2          06/09/2012 09/09/2012 FINISHED  
7  3          05/09/2012 06/09/2012 FINISHED    
8  3          06/09/2012 NULL       ACTIVE
```

What I need is a JOIN, which will give me Start and End times of Finished processes like below:

```
PROCESS_ID START_TIME END_TIME  
1          31/08/2012 10/09/2012  
2          31/08/2012 09/09/2012
```

What kind of JOIN statement do I need to write to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid pulling in PROCESS_ID 3, you need to aggregate and filter first

The HAVING clause will ensure you ignore all rows for PROCESS_ID 3 in the `STEP` table. A simple `WHERE END_TIME IS NOT NULL` or `WHERE .. 'FINISHED'` won't do it. Neither will aggregating after the JOIN

```
SELECT
   P.PROCESS_ID,
   S.StartTime, S.EndTime
FROM
   PROCESS P
   JOIN
   (
   SELECT
      PROCESS_ID,
      MIN(START_TIME) AS StartTime,
      MAX(END_TIME) AS EndTime
   FROM
      STEP
   GROUP BY
      PROCESS_ID
   HAVING
      COUNT(*) = COUNT(END_TIME) -- only where we have no END_TIME nulls
   ) S ON P.PROCESS_ID = S.PROCESS_ID
```

There are other options with a NOT EXISTS to ignore ACTIVE rows, for example, but I'm using just END_TIME and NULLs here to ignore STEP rows

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need an `INNER JOIN` and use the `MIN` and `MAX` functions.

```
SELECT PROCESS.PROCESS_ID, MIN(START_TIME), MAX(END_TIME)
FROM PROCESS
INNER JOIN STEP ON STEP.PROCESS_ID = PROCESS.PROCESS_ID
GROUP BY PROCESS.PROCESS_ID
```

Comment: Why are you joining step-table?

Comment: @Johanh - because STEP has a PROCESS_ID field that is common between  the two tables and contains the END_TIME field the OP is asking for.